# zlib not available error in spite of the package already installed

Tags: linux-mint, apt, software-installation

I am trying to install pip through -

> python3 get-pip.py

but it is giving ***zlib not available error***.

I have tried following commands -

1. ***sudo apt install zlib1g-dev*** [OUTPUT: zlib1g-dev is already the newest version]
2. ***sudo apt install -y zlib1g-dev zlibc*** [OUTPUT: E: Unable to locate package zlibc]
3. ***sudo apt install zlib-devel*** [OUTPUT: E: Unable to locate package zlib-devel]
4. ***sudo apt install zlib-deve*** [OUTPUT: E: Unable to locate package zlib-deve]

All the solutions I have looked up suggest doing at-least one of the above commands should fix this issue.

**Still I am getting "*zlib not available*" error.**

OS:
**Linux Mint 21.2 Cinnamon**

Comment: Is there a advantage of installing `pip` that way? If not you can install `pip` by running `sudo apt install python3-pip`.

Comment: @davidt930 Have seen some people saying on forums that installing pip that way insure that pip will by default always install python packages locally [/usr/local/lib/...]. Anyways, installing any module using pip also sometimes results in this error.

Comment: installing pip with apt is probably best.  At the very least, you'll get the correct dependencies that way.

Comment: @ReetNayan Welcome, I suggest using `pip` only in [virtual environments](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/installing-packages/#creating-and-using-virtual-environments) to avoid the problems you read in forums. *"venv is available by default in Python 3.3 and later, and installs pip and setuptools into created virtual environments in Python 3.4 and later."*

Comment: @MarcusMüller Although I agree with your comment, installing `pip` through `get-pip.py` is an alternative presented in the official docs of `pip`.

Comment: Do **not** follow people in random forums telling you to install some software in non-distribution ways. Davidt930 is right, there's no good reason to not install pip via apt. If you **really** need pip as system installed, and here's where @schrodingerscatcuriosity is right: it's universally a pretty bad idea to install things via `pip` system-wide, so you would want to use a virtualenv anyways, and then you can as well install pip inside that. Under *no* circumstance would you need to ever install `pip` from some script.

Comment: @schrodingerscatcuriosity had to re-post a typo-fixed version of my comment, sorry. Yes, I know, it's recommended by pip. But that official documentation could generally be more explicit that using pip has the general ability, tendency and no safeguards against messing up systems that ship python and packages; so I'm not too fond of it.

Comment: I understand but how do I fix this zlib issue?

Comment: @ReetNayan Trying to chase packages is a very problematic approach to solve your issue. There's no `zlibc` package or alike in the Ubuntu 22 repositories (Mint 21 is based on Ubuntu 22). If you just need to use `pip` try what's suggested in the comments instead of entering the hell of package dependencies.

Comment: @ReetNayan the issue is really with the method you chose – it assumes the presence of stuff that simply can't be there. That is the same problem as the problems it will lead to, when you succeed in making it work: it's fundamentally incompatible with your system, and *should not be done*. Full stop. Whatever motivated you to try and install pip this way – it will not give you what you want (which is a working pip and a system you don't break that way). So. Forget about this method, `sudo apt install python3-pip` takes around 10s and works, unlike this method.